# Checking whether number is in given range

Tags: java, interval

#### Introduction

I want to check whether number is in given range.
Function takes:

- **long** *number* that should be checked
- **2 longs** *threshold* values
- **byte** *range mode*

Range mode is represented as number of type **byte** that can be from 0 to 4

- **0 for 00** => exclusive check
- **3 for 11** => inclusive check
- **1 for 01** => maximum - inclusive, minimum - exclusive
- **2 for 10** => maximum - exclusive, minimum - inclusive

### Code

#### Range check constant flags

```
public static final byte RANGE_EXCLUSIVE = 0; // 00
public static final byte RANGE_INCLUSIVE = 3; // 11
public static final byte RANGE_MAX_INCLUSIVE = 1; // 01
public static final byte RANGE_MIN_INCLUSIVE = 2; // 10
```

#### Function

```
public static boolean inRange(long value, long range_a, long range_b, byte checkMode) {
    if (range_a > range_b) {
        long tmp = range_a;
        range_a = range_b;
        range_b = tmp;
    }

    // If value is on the left edge - check if it is inclusive
    if (value == range_a && (checkMode & RANGE_MIN_INCLUSIVE) == 0) return false;
    // If value is on the right edge - check if it is inclusive
    if (value == range_b && (checkMode & RANGE_MAX_INCLUSIVE) == 0) return false;

    // If value is out of range - return false
    if (value < range_a) return false;
    if (value > range_b) return false;

    return true;
}
```

### Question

What do you think about this code?

Should I throw exceptions if *range_a* is **less** than *range_b*?

Or I can return false because *range_a* is expected to be **less or equal** to *range_b*

My first(and current) variant was to swap their values so *range_a* is always minimum, and *range_b* is always maximum of them

### About style

I'm using camelcase for methods and variables

*Underscore* is used to show that values are connected. and used together:

Example: pos_x, pos_y **or** range_a, range_b

Comment: Why isn't `checkMode` an enumeration?

Comment: That is a very good question, @Alexander. I want to ask it too. Michael, why you aren't using enumerations? Oh, me? I did not thinked about that. Yes, we can get values ids, so it might be used the same way. But also it will protect the code and will help normal developres to use it. Thx for question!

Comment: You don't need to access the enum's raw values. You can use enum values directly in switches and equality comparison in if statements.

Comment: That is good way to. I need to tink what will be better. Switch will be easy to read, and code is small, so might be easy to check. Thx for pointing this :~)

Comment: It will be. The whole point of enums is to abstract away these irrelevant details about the backing representation of an enumerated choice.

Comment: But what is about ranges? Should i use range_min, range_max? Throw excceptions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52330/discussion-between-alexander-and-michael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully concur with @TimothyTruckle on format, follow his advice.

---

Using binaries is restrictive (only two states), and not user-friendly. I don't like byte arithmetics, its quite un-Java like. I suppose you come from C/C++ background.

In more Java-like syntax, I propose a fluent interface on a `Range` class:

```
public class Range {

     private static enum RangeType{ INCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, INFINITE };

     private static class RangeStart {
         private final RangeType startType;
         private final Double startValue;
         private RangeStart(RangeType type, Double value){
             this.startType = type;
             this.startValue = value;
         }
         public Range toInclusive(double endValue) {
              // Optionally check endValue >= startValue and throw something
              return new Range(startType, startValue, RangeType.INCLUSIVE, endValue);
         }
         public Range toExclusive(double endValue) {
              // Optionally check endValue >= startValue and throw something
              return new Range(startType, startValue, RangeType.EXCLUSIVE, endValue);
         }
         public Range toInfinity() {
              return new Range(startType, startValue, RangeType.INFINITY, 0.);
         }
     }

     public static RangeStart fromInfinity() {
          retur new RangeStart(RangeType.INFINITY, 0.)
     }

     public static RangeStart fromInclusive(double fromValue) {
          retur new RangeStart(RangeType.INCLUSIVE, fromValue)
     }

     public static RangeStart fromExclusive(double fromValue) {
          retur new RangeStart(RangeType.EXCLUSIVE, fromValue)
     }

     private final RangeType startType;
     private final Double startValue;
     private final RangeType endType;
     private final Double endValue;

     private Range(RangeType startType, Double startValue, RangeType endType, Double endValue) {
          this.startType  = startType;
          this.startValue = startValue;
          this.endType    = endType;
          this.endValue   = endValue;
     }

     public boolean contains(double value){
          // Do your thing here, I'm not doing all the work! ;-)
     }
}
```

This creates a re-usable Range object to check values. The Pattern used is similar to the Builder Pattern (I named the Builder `RangeStart`).

Example usage:

```
Range range5i7e = Range.fromInclusive(5).toExclusive(7);
range5i7e.contains(5); // true
range5i7e.contains(5); // false
Range.fromInclusive(-10).toInfinity().contains(3720); // true    Range.fromInclusive(5).toExclusive(3); // Throws something ?
```

---

Style improvements:

You may want to make inclusive the standard and use `Range.from(1).to(2)` to make a closed `Range`. It's much less verbose.

You could also make the Range infinite-ended on both sides unless otherwise told, like `Range.to(5)` would be `]Inf, 5]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I throw exceptions if range_a is less than range_b?

This depends on your requirements. 
 - Does the user of this function have to provide the input in correct order because a wrong order is a follow up of serious problem in her preceding code? Then you should throw an exception and this might even be a *checked* custom type to make the user aware of it.
 - Or is the wrong order something that is likely to happen and no problem outside your method? The reordering and going on inside your method is  appropriate.

> Should I throw exceptions if range_a is less than range_b?

This also must be specified by the requirements. If there was no requirement add a Javadoc comment explaining that and *why* you (not) return `true` in this situation.

> I'm using camelcase for methods and variables

as expected by the java naming conventions.

> *Underscore* is used to show that values are connected. and used together:
>   Example: pos_x, pos_y **or** range_a, range_b

Why not `posX`, `posY` and `rangeX`, `rangeY`

or even better: since Java is an *object oriented language*, why not using objects to group things that belong together?

```
class Tupel {
  long a,b;
  Tupel(int a, int b){
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }
}

Tupel pos = new Tupel(10,30);
Tupel range = new Tupe(5,59);
// ...
if (range.a > range.b) {
  range = new Tupel(range.b,range.a);
// ...
```

> Why isn't checkMode an enumeration? – Alexander

The good thing about Java enums is that they can hold logic. The enum constants are classes that extend the enum class. This way enums can improve your code by resolving `if`/`else` cascades or `switch` constructs with polymorphism.

> You don't need to access the enum's raw values.[...] – Alexander

With that in mind you have only 2 `enum` constants

```
enum CompareMode{
  RANGE_EXCLUSIVE{
    @Override
    protected abstract boolean isInRange(long value, long range_a, long range_b){
      return value > range_a && value < range_b;
    }
  },
  RANGE_INCLUSIVE{
    @Override
    protected abstract boolean isInRange(long value, long range_a, long range_b){
      return value >= range_a && value =< range_b;
    }
  };
  public boolean inRange(long value, long range_a, long range_b){
     if(range_a > range_b)
       return isInRange( value,range_b,range_a);
     else // <- not needed but her for readability
       return isInRange( value,range_a,range_b);       
  };
}
```

you complete logic is inside the enum, no extra method needed.

---

Now lets join that with the `Tupel` class:

```
enum CompareMode{
  RANGE_EXCLUSIVE{
    @Override
    protected abstract boolean isInRange(long value, Tupel range){
      return value > range.a && value < range.b;
    }
  },
  RANGE_INCLUSIVE{
    @Override
    protected abstract boolean isInRange(long value, Tupel range){
      return value >= range.a && value =< range.b;
    }
  };
  public boolean inRange(long value, Tupel range){
     if(range.a > range.b)
       range=new Tupel(range.b,range.a);
     return isInRange( value,range_a,range_b);       
  };
}
```

The benefit of that solution is:

- the parameter list is shorter and has no more possibility to mix the values passed in accidentally.
- if you later add another CompareMode (which is hard to imaging, but try...) the only thing you have to change is the lines for the new mode and the code where you decide which mode to use. The code that actually needs the result does not need to change.

---

> Also, how are you calling methods in enum? – Michael

like this:

```
   Tupel range = new Tupel(4,5);
   for(CompareMode compareMode : CompareMode.values()){
    System.out.println(4+" is in range with compareMode "+compareMode +" ="+compareMode.inRange(4,range);
    System.out.println(5+" is in range with compareMode "+compareMode +" ="+compareMode.inRange(5,range);
   }
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Nitpick 1: you're dealing twice with `should I throw`, Nitpick2: it's called a [Tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

Comment: So, it will be 4 methods for each check type. Also, how are you calling methods in enum?

Comment: @Michael *"So, it will be 4 methods for each check type. "* hwo do you count 4? I see one per type and one both have in common...

Comment: @SylvainBoisse *"Nitpick 1: [...], Nitpick2: [...]"* has been late yesterday, will fix it.

Comment: But if i need only min inclusive? And how to call them? CompareMode.inRange(.. ) or Cm..Mode.RANGE_INCLUSIVE.inRange(...)

Comment: @Michael Yes you would have 4 to have all combinations. Actually, I would advise more: you could specify half-open ranges, and because enums are easy to extend, it's dead simple. With bytes, it would not be possible (they have only 2 states!). With an enum specifying two bounds that can each be inclu/excl/inf that makes 9 cases. I would rather use one enum INCLUDE/EXCLUDE/INFINITE twice (left side, right side)

Comment: Maybe I will add also 'Boundary struct, that have type Iclusive/eclusive/infinite and value. I think it will be better

Comment: Nice approach, but I do not like the Tuple to be called Tuple. Yes, this effectively *is* just a grouping of two arbitrary numeric values, but here it serves as a Range or Interval, representing a business concept. Removing this business concept seems just as wrong as abusing a predefined Point class to represent a range concept.

Comment: @mtj *"I do not like the Tuple to be called Tuple. "* Neither me, but the OP metioned *pos* beside *range* which could also be a `Tuple` but would feel strange to be  *Range* (or vice versa).